# When Conjuring a weapon do you receive conjure points as well as one-handed weapon points?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I Love conjuring and I am an imperial. I have a conjure sword spell and I am wondering if it will give me exp toward conjuring as well as one-handed weapons.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You'll get one-handed skill when used in combat, just like any other one-handed weapon.

You get a conjuration skill up if and when you enter the range of hostile mobs. While summoning during combat will work just fine, you can also summon your weapon long before seeing any hostiles and still get skill: it just won't happen until you hostiles are within range of you.

This is a little confusing and counterintuitive, but to illustrate a few scenarios:

#### Scenario A

You summon your weapon while hostiles are around. You'll get a skill up for this.

#### Scenario B

You summon your weapon when nobody's around, and it expires before encountering anything.  You don't get a skill up for this.

#### Scenario C

You summon your weapon when nobody's around. You don't get any skill for this. While the summoned weapon is still active, you run into some hostiles. As soon as you do, you'll get a one-time skill up for the already-summoned weapon.

What's cool about scenario C is that summoned weapons act as a poor man's hostile radar: if you get a skill up in conjuration out of nowhere, you know you ran into some hostiles, even if they don't show up on the compass yet.

Comment: So is it just a flat one time lump of xp, or do you continually accrue xp while wielding a conjured weapon near enemies?

Comment: @Arkive one skill up per summon. It's just delayed until you enter a hostile situation.

Answer (score 1):

As you USE the swords in battle, it does increase your one handed skill. The only time you actually get a conjuration boost is, as he said, when you first summon the sword/axe/bow, whichever conjured weapon it may be (given that there are hostiles nearby, whether you see them or not). This was added to the game because too many people would just sit in a room and spam summons to get their conjuration to 100. A good way to exploit it in Skyrim, however, is to get in the range of a far-off archer. He'll shoot at you, but it won't do too much damage if you run back and forth. He won't charge at you, consider how he's an archer, and, while in his range, you can THEN start spamming the spell for exp boost.

What I don't know is whether or not the one-handed perks effect your conjured weapons. Such as the bleeding damage for axes carrying over to your summoned axe. Or the crit chance for sword. Or even the 20% boost to them at all. Any of you guys tried allocating points to one-handed them find that it affected your conjured weapons as well?

Comment: Yes they do. My conjured sword was 16 damage, I put one point into Armsman and now it is 20 damage, so I assume it is the same for the rest of the perks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. You gain exp in both.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently no, you will only receive conjuring points if you  summon it within combat, read this somewhere on one of the wiki's, can't remember if it was confirme