# How do spells affect skill leveling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim as a mage, and I am wondering how I can level up the skills for mage.

Alchemy and Destruction seem quite straightforward. However, many skills consist of mostly defensive spells: how do those affect skill progression?

For restoration, I notice healing gets increases my skill; does this only work if my health isn't full?

What about spells that create something (a light, armor rating, a weapon, summon, etc): when will those affect the skill? Does constant renewing increase skill, or is it useless?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you noticed, **Destruction** is pretty straightforward. Each cast and while continued casting, you will increase skill, but this has a caveat: *only if you are attacking someone*. If you're fizzling your spell in the middle of town, it's not going to increase it.

**Alchemy** is also straightforward: each potion created will increase your skill. As [dpatchery notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36511/how-does-leveling-work-with-spells-that-dont-have-a-target#comment-53183), eating ingredients for effect determination will also increase your skill by a small amount.

With **Enchanting**, each enchant (or disenchant, as [LessPop_MoreFizz notes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36511/how-does-leveling-work-with-spells-that-dont-have-a-target#comment-53186)) as will increase skill. dpatchery also notes that you can increase your skill by recharging items with soul gems.

**Restoration**, namely the healing spells, only increase skill if your health is below its maximum.  The others only work if you're in combat or near hostile enemies: this includes spells like *Steadfast Ward*.

For summoning spells (essentially most things in the **Conjuration** school), you won't get a skill up for the summon [until you enter the range of hostile mobs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36368/when-conjuring-a-weapon-do-you-receive-conjure-points-as-well-as-one-handed-weap/36402#36402) and, in the case of summoned creatures (like the Atronach and the Familiar), they do some damage. With bound weapons, entering range of hostile mobs is all that's necessary to gain Conjuration skill; however, using them in combat will increase their appropriate weapon skill, not Conjuration.

**Alteration** and **Illusion** spells that are targeted towards messing with hostile mobs need hostile mobs within range to skill up. Buffs, like *Oakflesh*, don't increase skill without hostility as well. Others, like *Candlelight* and *Muffle*, are recastable without hostility but only increase skill by a small amount.

Comment: Note that Alchemy is also increased slightly when eating ingredients to determine their effects. Enchanting is also increased when using a soul gem to replenish charges on a magic weapon.

Comment: @dpatchery Nice: didn't even think to test that. Added.

Comment: Similarly to Alchemy, Enchanting can also be leveled by *disenchanting* items to learn new effects.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah, good call: I did test that one but forgot about it. Added.

Comment: @MarkTrapp have you tried summoning a creature, hitting it enough to make it attack, and then casting spells like oakflesh and bound weapons? Might not be worth the effort for folks with low magicka/low magicka regen

Comment: Ah I remember the old glitches in TES2. There was a race of people who were supposed to be *resistant* to frost damage...that resistance turned into immunity. So you'd take a detriment of "Double damage from frost" (of course double of nothing is still nothing) and a benny of damage converted to mana. Find a corner and fire a spell repeatedly to boost the skill. Now you have to be engaged in combat for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer. I just found out you also get alchemy skill for failing to create a potion, probably less than for a succesful attempt.

Comment: A good way to level destruction and restoration is by finding a mamoth then cast flames and healing hands (one in each hand) you will kill and heal the mamoth at the same time. So stock up on potions and go at it, also for a large combo of upgrades, use transmute to change silver to gold then make rings, enchant the rings then sell them. You will level your alteration, smithing, enchanting, and speachcraft.....

Comment: @MarkTrapp also casting soul trap will increase the conjuration skill.

Comment: @Justin I'm wondering what is speachcraft?

Comment: @MarkTrapp RE: Illusion spells and leveling up with enemies around. From http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion#Gaining_Skill_XP : "*Casting Muffle on yourself repeatedly will level up your Illusion fast, even if there are no enemies around*".

Comment: @galacticninja I'm fully aware of how Muffle works: the question didn't ask for every single spell's affect on skill ups, but a general overview. I've updated my answer to mention it however.

Comment: Do Oakflesh or Stoneflesh give experience if I cast it somewhat far away from a mob and then walk in the group? (like near the end of the time)

Answer (score 5):

Yep, you can use the spell 'Muffle' to level up your magic just by walking around. Just cast it and walk around, and it'll increase your level and give you some exp!

Could be considered an exploit though.

---

> Quick Experience and Illusion Skill Gain
>
> While most spells require you to actively use them in combat
>   situations or on specific objects to progress, there is at least one
>   spell that doesn't: Muffle. Muffle is an Illusion spell that quiets
>   your movements. Continually casting Muffle while you're walking around
>   the land will not only boost your Illusion skill, but will also
>   increase your overall experience.
>   http://uk.ign.com/cheats/games/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-xbox-360-14267318

Answer (score 3):

Restoration only gives you experience when you heal damage.

Other spells are given experience upon every successful cast, so constant renewing will increase your bar.  It just takes longer to level in those areas.

As LessPop pointed out in the comments, conjuration gives you experience when your conjured weapon or conjured minion actually deals damage to an enemy.

Comment: It should be noted that Conjuration spells *do* actually award experience based on damage dealt/use of your summoned friends or items *in combat*. Spamming **Summon Atronach** will not work.

Comment: @LessPop good catch, I was thinking more along the lines the alteration spells, overlooked conjuration

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the spells level up ONLY through dealing damage - ie. the more damage points a spell does to an enemy, the more xp points you get in that discipline (so, casting Fire Bolt is a better use of your mana than Novice Flame).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in some of the other answers, there are a few spells that allow you to easily level up a school all by yourself. I find that both Muffle (illusion) and Telekinesis (alteration) work great on your own.