# How to Level Magic Skills as a Warrior

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It seems to me that to get to level 80 I will need to level *all* my skills to 100. Easier said than done though.

As a non-magic-using warrior, how can I level my various magic skills?  Let's ignore Restoration, I actually use that from time to time. But how can I level up the other skill trees?

Comment: I want to say this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the post I was thinking of...

Comment: Not a duplicate but the first answer of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36511/how-do-spells-affect-skill-leveling would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the question asks *"How to Level Magic Skills as a Warrior"* the reason why you ask this, as stated in the question body, is because you want to get to Level 80.

> It seems to me that to get to level 80 I will need to level all my skills to 100. Easier said than done though. 
>   
>  
>   As a non-magic-using warrior, how can I level my various magic skills? Let's ignore Restoration, I actually use that from time to time. But how can I level up the other skill trees?

you can do this and more without even touching magic skills since the 1.9 Patch which allows your skills to become [Legendary](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skills_(Skyrim)#Legendary_Skills)

> The purpose of making a skill Legendary is to allow it to contribute to increasing character level again. In Skyrim, character levels are gained by leveling up one's Skills. When all skills reach 100, the character can no longer gain character levels (this occurs at level 81). Making skills Legendary allows skill leveling to continue, which in turn allows character level to continue to rise.

this means you just need to make your Warrior-centric skills Legendary and just keep working on them, as such to reach Level 80 you don't need to level up every skill to 100, just the ones your going to use far more often

otherwise if you are looking to make your Warrior a magic user regardless, the answers [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36511/how-do-spells-affect-skill-leveling) (provided by [Studoku's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194961/how-to-level-magic-skills-as-a-warrior#comment264076_194961)), particular the accepted answer is a good reference

Comment: Well, *that* is an interesting patch. I wonder what it will be like to be a level 300 warrior with a weapon skill of 1. I guess it's time to find out.

Comment: Don't you autoinstall the patches?

Comment: @Ids probably if you played on a computer connected to the Internet, my computer doesn't so whenever I needed to get a patch I had to locate an installer (and in some cases updated offline crack). For Skyrim however my mum picked up the Legendary Edition from a garage sale (what idiots) and it came with 1.9. You can also miss patches on consoles if you aren't connected to the Internet

Comment: True enough. I think you missed the biggest reason for not patching ;). Arr and all that.

Answer (score 1):

> Alteration
>   To easily level Alteration, purchase the Telekinesis spell from Tolfdir at the College of Winterhold. To gain access to the College of Winterhold you will need to complete a quest called First Lessons. Once you have the Telekinesis spell, just drop an item to the ground and keep bringing the item to yourself. You will get skill experience every time you cast the spell, making Alteration very easy to level up.
>
> Conjuration
>   To easily level Conjuration, purchase the Soul Trap spell from Phinis Gestor at the College of Winterhold. To gain access to the College of Winterhold you will need to complete a quest called First Lessons. Once you have the Soul Trap spell, find a dead body and continuously cast Soul Trap on it. You will get skill experience every time you cast the spell, making Conjuration very easy to level up
>
> Illusion
>   To easily level Illusion, purchase the Courage spell from Farengar Secret-Fire in Dragonsreach. Once you have the Courage spell, find a living person and continuously cast Courage on him or her. You will get skill experience every time you cast the spell, making Illusion very easy to level up
>
> Steal Anything
>   NPCs cannot see you if you place an object over their head, such as a bucket, basket, or kettle. Make sure everyone in the room has something over their head and you can steal something right in front of them without them noticing. You cannot pickpocket them without them noticing though.
>
> Pickpocket Anything
>   Obtain all three words for the Unrelenting Force shout. Find an isolated NPC like Eorlund Gray-Mane in Whiterun. Knock him down with the shout (using all three words) and as he is getting back up try to pickpocket him. You should be able to pickpocket everything, even if it says your chance is 0%. Save before attempting this as sometimes your shouts will kill the NPC.

http://clevermusings.net/2011/11/elder-scrolls-skyrim-exploit-guide/

Comment: While it's good you attributed where you got this from, all you've done is copy/paste from the link.  You grabbed some irrelevant information, and didn't even grab all the magic school information.  I'd suggest also adding in some original information, so your entire answer isn't just a straight copy and paste.